# Wordpress: Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php, wordpress

The WordPress Website I got access to is not loading. I checked the error_log file from CPanel - the last lines are:

> [10-Jan-2019 14:24:49 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /home/indianlu/1callglobal.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 2177
>
> [22-May-2019 00:14:01 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() in
>   /home/indianlu/1callglobal.com/wp-admin/includes/update-core.php on
>   line 1385

How can I possibly fix this?

Comment: You might want to raise your memory to be more than 256M, both in your php.ini and in your wp-config

Comment: Do you have access to the PHP configuration? i.e. `php.ini`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The famous Wordpress white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400187/the-famous-wordpress-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress : Fatal error: Allowed memory ... exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460667/wordpress-fatal-error-allowed-memory-exhausted)